# Flatten PDF form

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, javascript

I'm not able to implement the soluton provided here in [Including Javascript to flatten PDF form made in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340607/including-javascript-to-flatten-pdf-form-made-in-latex). A MWE will be helpful. Thank you.

**Edit**

Added MWE.
Frankly I'm not sure if I've put the `\pdfcatalog` at the right place. I also don't know how to use it. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfcatalog{/AA << % additional actions
    /WS << % "will save"
    /S/JavaScript /JS (this.flattenPages();)
    >>
    >>}
\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        {\large \textbf{Reviewed by:}}      &   \TextField[bordercolor={},name = ReviewerName, width = 0.45\textwidth, value={}]{}\\ \hline 
        {\large \textbf{Date:}}  & \TextField[bordercolor={},name = DateReviewer, width = 0.45\textwidth, value={}]{}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, an MWE would be helpful for the people trying to help you...

Comment: Hi @Abby, I'm trying to exactly as stated in the question in the link. I would like to flatten the pdf while saving after the form is filled.

Comment: Right, but now we have to assume that you created the form correctly, are running the javascript correctly, tried the answer as provided there, and it doesn't work? How can we help you if we don't know what *exactly* you have tried and where you got stuck? What I'm trying to say is that you are way more likely to get help when you provide 1) a minimal latex document that includes a minimal form (one field is enough) and includes the answer from the question you are referring to, 2) a minimal javascript script that should flatten this pdf, and 3) how you are compiling and running everything.

Comment: Then we should be able to reproduce your problem and hopefully someone will be able to help you. Honestly, it sounds like you have an interesting problem and I am more than willing to help you, but right now I have no idea how to get started to reproduce your problem, as I have no idea what exactly your problem even is.

Comment: @Abby I've added the MWE for your referance. Please let me know if anything else is required from my side. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The function `flattenPages` is marked with  in its availability column ( `js_api_reference.pdf`, version 8.1, 2007-04):

> The property or method is not allowed in Adobe Reader but is available
> in Acrobat Professional and Acrobat Standard.

Currently (2021), the "JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference" is available
at ["Adobe DC SDK/Documentation"](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/documentation.html). There is a link [Download a zip of all PDF docs](https://www.adobe.com/go/acrobatsdk_doczip) to download all PDF documentation files. The HTML link in the table above is currently broken (404).

Comment: Hi @Heiko is there any alternative way this can be achieved ?

Comment: @ShastriD Often *printing* to PDF flattens the file. Or save it in Adobe Reader and run the file through `ps2pdf` from Ghostscript.

Comment: I'm aware of printing but I want to make it more user friendly as managers will be using the files.